# Compare two numbers without jle

Tags: assembly

Is there a way tompare two numbers stored in registers without using a conditional jump other than JE / JNE ?
Only the following instructions: ADD, SUB, AND, OR, XOR, NEG, left and right arithmetic shift, CMP, and MOV.

Comment: what assembly language is that? for which architecture?

Comment: What do you mean by “compare”?  `JE` and `JNE` by themselves don't compare numbers; they simply look at the `Z` flag.  All of the arithmetic instructions you named, and `CMP`, set or clear the `Z` flag as appropriate.  You need explain more thoroughly what you need to do.

Comment: This is in a reduced instruction set assembly language, I still have the Z flag on but it only says if the last operation gave 0 or not.
The instructions I named set the Z flags as I said, that it to say true or false.

Comment: Assuming wrap-around on underflow, you can compare for equality by subtracting the two values and then test if the zero flag became set.

Comment: It's true, but actually I'm searching to do the following :
a < b (thank you though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmp EAX,EDX
jle xxx
```

is equivalent to

```
sub EDX,EAX
shr EDX,31
jz xxx
```